# d3 : do I really need to call all the enter block when updating data?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am building a d3 graph, and I want to be able to update/remove data based on user actions.

I have read the documentation about the update pattern, that can be found [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234)

What I see is, everytime that we want to refresh the graph because of a dataset change, we need to call the update function, which basically unrolls ALL the d3 setup again. In some other tutorials like [this one](http://pothibo.com/2013/09/d3-js-how-to-handle-dynamic-json-data/), I have found that you can only call the enter block when you want to refresh, but still, you call the whole enter setup !

I am a bit confused about the pattern, for me it looks like it violates the DRY principle. Ideally, I was expecting a function to tell d3 that the whole data array has changed, or tell d3 which particular data have been added/changed/removed, without having to give all the enter setup again. Does it exist or do I have to stick with this pattern ?

Comment: If you don't have **more** data points than elements in the DOM when you update your chart, you indeed don't need the enter selection, you just need the update selection, and the enter selection can be removed without any visible consequence. However, it's a good practice to write D3 codes specifying the enter, update and exit selections, since sometimes we don't know the data length.

Comment: I am perfectly fine with defining enter/exit/update methods. My point is, I don't want to call this setup again when I actually want to change my data.

Comment: As I explained, if your new data don't have more data points than the older one, you don't need an enter selection. If, on the other hand, you do have more data points, you need to set the enter selection. There is no "alternative", since this is the idiomatic D3 way of creating new DOM elements based on bound data.